# Independent family of $\sigma$-algbras which forms a semi-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Im trying to prove this result

**Lemma:** Let $(\mathcal{M_{i}})_{i\in I} \subset \mathcal{F}$ family of independent $\sigma$-algebras over $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$ probability space. Then, for $i_{1}, i_{2} \in I$ two different elements of I, we have that the set $\mathcal{C}:=\{A\cap B, A\in \mathcal{M_{i_{1}}}$ and $B\in \mathcal{M_{i_{2}}}\}$ is a semi algebra.

Im really stuck at proving that the disjoint finite union of the complements of elements in $\mathcal{C}$ is in fact in $\mathcal{C}$. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks so much <3

Comment: What do you mean by "three different elements"?

Comment: Two* haha, and that means, elements of the family $(M_{i})_{i\in I}$. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Don't you need a measure to define independence? Or what else would the definition be?

Comment: Edited, sorry for the trouble <3